# Merging two rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table. It describes how many times user1 has started a conversation with user2 ("A started a conversation with B, 5 times"):

```
user1  user2  count
-------------------
A      B      5
A      C      2
B      A      6
B      C      1
C      A      9
C      B      4
```

However, I would like to merge rows between similar users. So user1:A and user2:B is the same as user1:B and user2:A, leading to the following result:

```
user1  user2  count
-------------------
A      B      11 (5 + 6)
A      C      11 (2 + 9)
B      C      5
```

My first thought was to SELECT the table to PHP, loop through it, add rows and INSERT the result back into a new table. But this seems very redundant (and slow, since the table contains thousands of records). Is this also possible to do with (My)SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(user1, user2), GREATEST(user1, user2), SUM(count) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY LEAST(user1, user2), GREATEST(user1, user2)
```

Comment: @Pr0no are you planning on doing some narrowing of the query before you do this row compression? If so, you'll hit some snags. For instance, in the above query you won't have access to the `LEAST(user1, user2)` unless you use a `HAVING` block, but you won't mucking with the entire table unless you use a `WHEN` block. Just be careful.

Comment: @RobertMartin - Why do you suggest that you need a `HAVING` block to use `LEAST()`?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least

Comment: @Dems What I meant is you won't have access to the column. If Mark had done `LEAST(user1, user2) AS userX, GREATEST(user1, user2) AS userY` then the WHERE clause cannot use `userX` or `userY`. As you suggest, though, you can simply run the `LEAST` calculation a second time on each row.

Comment: @RobertMartin Could you elaborate? I'm unfimiliar with the term "narrowing of the query". If this answers your question: there will be no other operations on the table while the query is executing. It is for a research project. The database isn't live. It's living on my desktop with me being the only user :-)